# SQL Generate Word Template

Tags: asp.net, sql, ms-word, sql-agent-job

I have a MS Word Template .dot. I would like to use the SQL database to fill-in the data inside the bookmarks of the .dot file and save the document on a file server. What would be my best option? Would SSIS handle this? Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do that in SSIS but not without some scripting via the script task.  How comfortable are you with c# or vb?  Have you ever worked with the [Microsoft Office Object library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d2tx7z6d%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)?

Frankly, when I'm staring down the barrel of that much scripting I usually skip SSIS and simply write a full blown c# app.